# Explanation of MathML DTD Syntax

Tags: xml, dtd

I was reading the MathML DTD. I came across a line of code. Below is the line of code.

```
<!ENTITY % mathml-qname.module "INCLUDE">
<![%mathml-qname.module; [<!ENTITY % mathml-qname.mod PUBLIC "-//W3C//ENTITIES    MathML   3.0 Qualified Names 1.0//EN" "mathml3-qname.mod"> %mathml-qname.mod;]]>
```

I could not understand the above two line. Can anybody explain the syntax?

Answer (score 1):

This line:

```
<!ENTITY % mathml-qname.module "INCLUDE">
```

is a parameter entity. (A parameter entity can only be used in a DTD.) The value of the entity is "INCLUDE".

This line:

```
<![%mathml-qname.module; [<!ENTITY % mathml-qname.mod PUBLIC "-//W3C//ENTITIES    MathML   3.0 Qualified Names 1.0//EN" "mathml3-qname.mod"> %mathml-qname.mod;]]>
```

is another parameter entity that points to an external file with additional entity declarations. The difference is that it is wrapped in a conditional section. Basically is looks like this after `mathml-qname.module` is resolved:

```
<![INCLUDE [<!ENTITY % mathml-qname.mod PUBLIC "-//W3C//ENTITIES    MathML   3.0 Qualified Names 1.0//EN" "mathml3-qname.mod"> %mathml-qname.mod;]]>
```

This means the `mathml-qname.mod` declaration and reference will be included. If `INCLUDE` was changed to `IGNORE` in `mathml-qname.module`, the declaration and reference for `mathml-qname.mod` would be ignored.

Answer (score 1):

The first line declares a parameter entity named `mathml-qname.module` with the value "`INCLUDE`".

```
<!ENTITY % mathml-qname.module "INCLUDE">
```

The next bit I'm going to break up into several lines.

```
<![%mathml-qname.module; [
<!ENTITY % mathml-qname.mod PUBLIC 
  "-//W3C//ENTITIES    MathML   3.0 Qualified Names 1.0//EN" 
  "mathml3-qname.mod"> 
  %mathml-qname.mod;
]]>
```

The first and last lines (`<![%mathml-qname.module;[` ... `]]>`) are a conditional section -- that is, a section which may be read and processed normally, or skipped, depending on the value of its keyword.  The keyword appears between the two left square brackets -- here, it's given by a reference to the parameter entity `mathml-qname.module`.  If we expand the parameter entity reference, the conditional section looks like this:

```
<![INCLUDE [
 ...
]]>
```

As you might guess, the meaning of the keyword `INCLUDE` is:  include, read, and process this section. (The other possible value is `IGNORE`.)

Within the marked section there is another parameter entity declaration, for a parameter entity named `mathml-qname.mod`.  The `PUBLIC` keyword gives a public and a system identifier for the entity; to make a long story short, the entity in question is a collection of entities for MathML 3.0 qualified names, and it's located at the resource whose relative URI (relative to the resource containing this parameter entity declaration) is `mathml3-qname.mod`.

Following the parameter entity declaration for `mathml-qname.mod`, there is a reference to the same parameter entity (`%mathml-qname.mod;`), which causes the entity to be read and processed.

In informal terms:  this block of code specifies that by default, the external resource `mathml3-qname.mod` should be consulted.  But the user can override that default by including a parameter entity declaration of the following form at an appropriate location in their configuration:

```
<!ENTITY % mathml-qname.module "IGNORE">
```

You might do that if you had a different set of declarations for the qualified name entities of MathML 3.0.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I understoond.